# How to make one of my view to be only landscape

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, landscape

In my project i have 3 views for some reason one of my view has to support landscape and portrait but the problem is, i want one of my view only support landscape is there any way to do that?

My code written on objective -c

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the below method in your viewcontroller and that should do what you want

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape; // enforces the landscape orientation
}
```

Comment: @user7430661 how does it behave when you do this?

Answer (score 0):

NO, you can only configure whether the app, as a whole, can support landscape mode or not. 
 You *cannot* support landscape for one view & not for others.

Comment: Hi @ystack, i am sure it is possible, in past i did but i forgot now :(

Comment: @user7430661 I'm pretty sure OS _cannot_ support landscape for one view & not for others. Can you provide more details about the behaviour you are referring to?